# Slack Markdown for Links Are Not Resolving

Tags: markdown, slack-api, slack

What am I doing wrong? None of the example Markdown links work so far in my Slack app.

I pasted in the example below in a chat in my Slack app. I got this example from [slack markdown syntax](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting) and it still treats it as literal text in the Slack App:

```
[like this](http://someurl)
```

so I end up seeing that instead of just "like this" as a link in Slack chat.

Or maybe the above is wrong, in which case my question would then be how do you do explicitly create links in Slack? I want some text that I specify to be clickable to a specific URL (hyperlink).

Comment: Seems to be unresolved bug (doesn't work for me either) https://github.com/slackhq/hubot-slack/issues/114

Comment: not only the are not implementing this functionality, they also do not include a dark theme! this is outrageous for such a popular tool..on the other hand this is how popular tools become unpopular all of the sudden ...

Comment: Slack markdown link syntax is ```<http://someurl|like this>``` not the same as github. I think you are right that some of the Slack examples used to have that mistake in them, but github syntax does not work.

Answer (score 248):

Slack uses their own flavor of markdown:
Slack Markdown Links work in the following way: `<http://someurl|like this>`

Note: **You can only do this via the Slack API and NOT just as a simple message you send via the Slack client.**

[Message Builder Example](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fsomeurl%7Clike%20this%3E%22%7D)
[image]
[More Info in the Docs](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting#linking_to_urls)

Comment: is there a way to do this via the Slack client?

Comment: I don't think so. Slack explicitly does not want to overcomplicate input.
More at the bottom of this help article: https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202288908-Formatting-your-messages

Comment: One way they could have avoided overcomplication would have been to stick with a popular and well-established format ... like Markdown. ;-)

Comment: +joeytwiddle That would mean Slack intentionally doing something that is user friendly and intuitive, which I'm pretty sure is against their company policy.

Comment: @PeterR It's pretty disappointing that slack doesn't **FULLY** support markdown in messages like [gitter.im](https://gitter.im/).

Comment: Please upvote this feature request here : https://slack.canny.io/feature-requests/p/as-a-user-i-can-use-markdown-hyperlink-formatting-in-messages

Comment: Calling this a flavor of markdown is misleading. It's really more "their own formatting that sometimes looks a bit like markdown".

Comment: you could also use this for email like <mailto:abc@example.com|Alice>

Comment: @JulesRandolph link is broken

Comment: Today was the nth (where n>10) time that I wrote a `[title](url)` link in the Slack client, spent a minute trying to figure out if I had a typo somewhere, reversed the order of () and [], and then googled the syntax just to find this answer. How is this *less* complicated?

Comment: I use the slack client and the [solution below worked perfectly for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68711870/5765319)

Comment: In the API, it looks like longer URLs don't work with this syntax, but there's no specific limit documented in the docs.

Answer (score 194):

<s>Slack currently does not support hyperlinks; see [this link](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/204399343-Sharing-links-in-Slack) which says:</s>

> **Note**: It’s not possible to hyperlink words in a Slack message.

---

**UPDATE:**

Slack has finally added this functionality to their chat interface ([source](https://slack.com/intl/en-ca/help/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages-Format-your-messages)):

> - Select text, then click the  link icon in the formatting toolbar
> - Select text, then press `Cmd`+`Shift`+`U` on Mac or `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`U` on Windows/Linux.
>
> Copy the link you'd like to share and paste it in the empty field under **Link**, then click **Save**.

Comment: The question is specifically about the `slack-api` which **does** support hyperlinked text.

Comment: This is unfortunate. Hyperlink has been around for more than 20 years, it's hard to assume this is a security issue. Pasting super long links is really annoying, at least slack should add an automatic URL shortening service (which would be optional of course).

Comment: It seems this is now possible. But I'm unable to get it to work. No matter what I do Slack just receives `Array` as the message in the channel. See the examples here: https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/formatting#linking-urls

Comment: The original question asks about achieving this using markdown. This answer seems unrelated.

Comment: Worth mentioned that none of these work if you select `Format messages with markup` in the settings, to get rid of the text formatting toolbar.

Comment: This is useful information but it does not answer the question, which is specifically about using Markdown. Much confusion here, since there's the slack WSIWYG editor, there's slack markdown in the client, and then there's markdown in the slack API. I think the original question is about markdown in the client (at least that's what I'm wanting to do). Apparently [it is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47212827/9291019), and Slack has disabled feature requests.

Answer (score 56):

As of August 2021 this feature is finally enabled for markup mode in slack app. Enable markup mode in `Preferences` -> `Advanced` -> `Input options` -> `Format messages with markup`.

https://slack.com/help/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages#markup

```
Surround text with brackets, then surround the link with parentheses:
[your text](the link)
```

Comment: Confirmed that `[label](link)` does now work in the Slack app, but FYI this is no longer documented on the page referenced in this answer.

Comment: Thank you! You have made my day, month, year, and century.

Comment: but, at least on the mac app, this only works if you disable the WYSIWYG editor. unclear why they force seemingly unnecessary tradeoffs across either editor.

Comment: FYI, this still doesn't work in the API.  Links still have to be in the older `<L|T>` format.

Comment: It does have to be a valid URL, e.g. directly copying `the link` as in the example doesn't parse, but putting for example `[your text](stackoverflow.com)` does work. Thank you!

Answer (score 34):

This is not yet supported by Slack for direct messages, you can only do this using Slack API. But you can upvote [the feature request I have submitted here](https://slack.canny.io/feature-requests/p/as-a-user-i-can-use-markdown-hyperlink-formatting-in-messages).

Comment: Sorry, broken link :(

Comment: They seem to have disabled their canny channel to gather feature requests. Hope that is only temporary.

Comment: The link isn't broken. They intentionally disabled the board. Grr.

Comment: Everyday I seem to discover a new reason to dislike slack.

Answer (score 32):

As of today, 2020.02.14, in **one** of the Slack instances I'm a member in, I can create/paste hyperlinks!

[image: hyperlink screenshot]

Example pasting hyperlink from copy Teams meeting info into Slack:

[image: paste hyperlink example]

---

Slack has updated [their documentation](https://slack.com/help/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages-Format-your-messages#:~:text=link).  Still no markdown way of doing it though , i.e.  `[blah](https://stackoverflow.com)` doesn't work.

---

Neat feature, select some text and CTRL + V when a URL is on the clipboard and it creates a hyperlink

[image: select text & ctrl + v video]]

---

Through some reverse engineering I was able to put text on the Windows Clipboard via C# and get it to paste into Slack:

```cs
var textToDisplay = "Test";
var url = "https://stackoverflow.com";
var arbitraryText = "Mike D.";
var dataObject = new DataObject();
//to my surprise, the Fragment comments ARE required
dataObject.SetData(DataFormats.Html, @$"<html><body>
    <!--StartFragment-->
    <a href=""{url}"">{textToDisplay}</a>
    <!--EndFragment-->
    </body></html>");
//have to set the Text format too otherwise it won't work
dataObject.SetData(DataFormats.Text, arbitraryText);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject);
```

Comment: Upvoted because this is essentially the answer. Love the paste-to-linkify, love the hotkey... unfortunately I have disabled their WYSIWYG so that it stops messing with other things I'm trying to write, and there doesn't seem to be any alternative for those of us happy using markdown(-ish) formatting in plain text.

Comment: [@Tyler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2506703/tyler-james-young). I'm glad I'm not the only one that does this too!

Comment: I managed to make it work without the fragment comments

Comment: I rather _hate_ the hotkey, Ctrl+Shift+U has been used for unicode character input on Linux (ibus input method) for decades

Comment: My slack has the link tool, but I'd really love to just do it with the markdown [text](url) like [their docs say should work[(https://slack.com/help/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages).

Comment: Is there a JavaScript equivalent using navigator.clipboard.write ?

Comment: @timblaktu yes, you can do it with `Preferences` -> `Advanced` -> `Input options` -> `Format messages with markup` (see [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68711870/1159167)); as of Oct 2022, you would have to give up the text formatting toolbar .

Comment: It seems like this would just cause the text "Mike D." to be pasted into Slack.

Answer (score 28):

If you are using slack-bot or something that uses Slack API, you'll be able to use `mrkdwn` syntax for your messages.

```
<http://www.example.com|This message is a link>
```

Reference: *https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting*

Comment: As of December 2023 this is the right answer. None of the other solutions here work anymore.

Answer (score 7):

[Reuben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6835713/reuben)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49565612/7370789) will work, but it will look like an untitled file upload, as seen here: [untitled file posted to Slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPzNd.png). With a slight modification, however, you can easily post a natural looking message featuring a working hyperlink such as you see here: [natural looking Slack post with hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyZSu.png) by using the [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) Slack api method instead of "files.upload" and adopting Slack's own [message formatting](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting) instead of Markdown. That would be done like this:

```
curl -F text="*<https://someurl|like this>*" -F as_user=true -F link_names=true -F channel=C1.....7L -F token=xoxp-... https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage
```

The `link_names=true` argument isn't used in this example, but is useful to be able to `@`mention users and `#`refer to channels.

Answer (score 6):

My markup setting was disabled, once I've enabled it (Preferences -> Advanced -> Format messages with markup) it worked.

[image]

Comment: It's not great in terms of usability that those are "exclusive".

Comment: Great thanks! Indeed not great that they are explusive, a bit stupid even, but I only need the markup in some specific cases, and now I can enable it when needed.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to Slack Messages (covered in [Wilhem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2162900/wilhelm-klopp)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36304585/6835713)), you can create Slack Posts via the API and use at least some Markdown. These both create `<h2><a href="https://someurl">like this</a></h2>`:

```
curl -F filetype=post -F content="# [like this](https://someurl)" -F channels=C1.....7L -F token=xoxp-... https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```

or swap `content="..."` for `file=@post.md`

```
curl -F filetype=post -F file=@post.md -F channels=C1.....7L -F token=xoxp-... https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```

This is using [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload). I think the easiest way to try posting as yourself is with [a legacy token](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens). Get the channel ID from the URI of the channel.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this code to convert markdown links within a body of text into the link format slack expects:

```
// Pretty hacky, convert [sup](http://example.com) to <http://example.com|sup>
const reformatLinks = /\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/g
const slackBody = body.replace(reformatLinks, (_m, text, url) => `<${url}|${text}>`)
```

From what I can tell slack does not support image links inside text.

Answer (score 1):

None of the markup in the other answers here (Markdown, `<a|b>`, etc.) works anymore.

If you're composing by hand, there's something that to me is better than the keyboard shortcut in the docs (since that shortcut conflicts with global defaults on Linux and is a pain to work around).

Copy your URL to the clipboard, then **select the text you'd like to be the anchor text, and just paste the URL** as if you were going to replace the selected text with the URL.  Slack instead automatically turns the selected text into a link.

Comment: This is the only solution for now. Markdown for some stuff works in slack, but links don't. Thx Kev.

Answer (score 1):

Following spottedmahn's answer, here's how I got it working in Javascript. Note that for Firefox, the user needs to [enable a flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardItem#browser_compatibility) for this to work.

```
a.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var textToDisplay = "foo";
    var url = "https://stackoverflow.com";
    var message = `<html><body>
    <!--StartFragment-->
    <a href="${url}">${textToDisplay}</a>
    <!--EndFragment-->
    </body></html>`;
    const htmlBlob = new Blob([message], {type : 'text/html'});
    const textBlob = new Blob(["sda"], {type : 'text/plain'});

    const cbi = new ClipboardItem({
        ['text/html']: htmlBlob,
        ['text/plain']: textBlob
    });
    navigator.clipboard.write([cbi]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a problem with this form of markdown when the url is involving a vertical bar |
solved this with urltext.replace("|", "%7C")

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set-up a bot for Slack to send a message with markdown formatting there are few subtilies to know.

Here are some I have faced :

- Bold : `*word*` to have **word**
- link : `<url|string>` to have [string](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: For Slack, the link is actually `<string|url>`.

Answer (score -7):

Super late to the party but I recently discovered that you can use a URL shortener to create a https link which you can then reference using markdown links.

Comment: Why would using a URL shortener be of any help here?